# Why is Git refusing to merge unrelated histories?

Tags: git

```
$ git pull origin master
From github.com:hansaurusrex/destroytheworld
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

$ --allow-unrelated-histories
-bash: --allow-unrelated-histories: command not found
```

Hi guys, this might be a dumb question but I am having a bit of a problem merging. I read that it could be solved by using *--allow-unrelated-histories* however that doesn't work too. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you mean `git pull --allow-unrelated-histories` ?

Comment: Start by formatting your code and explaining what it is you are facing and how you want to solve it. The professionalism on this site does not extend to reading minds.

Comment: `--allow-unrelated-histories` is a *flag*, not an executable program in its own right. Pass it as an argument, don’t try to call it.

Comment: Read about [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) and its [`--allow-unrelated-histories`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#git-merge---allow-unrelated-histories) option.

Answer (score 1):

Apples-MacBook-Pro-3:DestroyTheWorld apple$ **git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories**

*Thank you everyone for your kind help! also apologies if my question was too ambiguous. Im currently learning to code in swift via DEVSLOPES. and Somehow the tutorial segwayed into git. Im new to git so im very unfamiliar with the syntax and functions. could someone be so kind as to point me to a good site to get some strong foundations?*